# Media queries not work in Firefox, when has animation

Tags: animation, firefox, media-queries

When the screen width is less than 640px, the background is covered, why is the height not covered? And, It's work in Chrome and Edge.

```
.change{
  background: #f00;
  height: 100px;
  animation: test1 1s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes test1 {
  0% {
    height: 100px;
  }
  
  100% {
    height: 400px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .change{
    background: #0f0;
  }
  
  
  @keyframes test1 {
    0% {
      height: 100px;
    }

    100% {
      height: 200px;
    }
  }
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wq3opugr/11/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at how the site behaves on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, it seems that Chrome might be the only browser who deviate by attempting to reanimate the `<div>` after `@media` conditions are changed. Firefox and Safari thought that the animation is finished and no longer needed to reanimated.

As a workaround, you can force all web browsers to reanimate this by re-setting the `.change` animation properties under the `@media` scope and changing their values by a bit, such as by animating for 1.000001 seconds instead of 1.

```css
.change{
  background: #f00;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  animation: test1 1s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes test1 {
  0% {
    height: 100px;
  }
  
  100% {
    height: 400px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .change{
    background: #0f0;
    color: #00f;
    animation: test1 1.000001s linear forwards;
  }
  
  
  @keyframes test1 {
    0% {
      height: 100px;
    }

    100% {
      height: 200px;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0' name='viewport' />
    <body>
      <div class="change">Some content</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've also opened a bug report related to this: https://webcompat.com/issues/108367